# Syntax highlighting and export EPUB format

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, syntax-highlighting, epub

I need to write RTL format and finaly export as Epub (pdf as freedom).I need to explain my codes and somthing such as syntax highlighting, Do you have any solution?

**UPDATE:**

My question has 2 aspect:
1. a software that i can write that such as libreoffice

2. a file format to export from which such as LateX

Comment: Did you mean the RTF file format?

Comment: No. I think to update my question.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh Could you please clarify what is meant by "RTL"? Is this right-to-left?

Comment: RTL languages such as Arabic, Persian and so on....

Comment: I found a libreoffice extension that is parse code and and do syntax highlighting, But i answer -4hour, You can test it.It's very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the following libreoffice extension:
[Code Colorizer Formatter](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/code-colorizer-formatter)